# Google Analytics Data API (GA4) - item.variant dimension?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-data-api

So, ga4-ecommerce has the property "variant" for it's items:
(see https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ecommerce-ga4)

```
dataLayer.push({
  event: "view_item_list",
  ecommerce: {
   items: [
    {
      item_name: "Triblend Android T-Shirt",       // Name or ID is required.
      item_id: "12345",
      price: 15.25,
      item_brand: "Google",
      item_category: "Apparel",
      item_category2: "Mens",
      item_category3: "Shirts",
      item_category4: "Tshirts",
      item_variant: "Gray",
      item_list_name: "Search Results",
      item_list_id: "SR123",
      index: 1,
      quantity: 1
    },
});
```

But somehow I don't seem to find the dimension for item.variant. Pretty much every other prop is represented by its own dimension in the API-Schema:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema#dimensions

Is this by design and I can somehow retrieve aggregated metrics based on variant?

f.e. I want to retrieve aggregated data to see how much itemViews (metric) each itemVariant (the dimension I'm missing?) generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way to retrieve the `itemVariant` dimension in the GA4 Data API. The dimensions from the item array are prefixed with the string `item` in the [API Dimensions & Metrics list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema#dimensions).

The GA4 Data API presents most of the dimensions available in the GA4 UI; an `Item Variant` dimension is also not available in the GA4 UI.

Comment: So, is there a suggested way to get this metric anyway, maybe store it as a different one?

Answer (score 0):

I was setting up a new build and decided the best way to keep this was to drop "category 4" and use that instead. Understand this won't work for build's with historical data using the category 4/5 for their intended purposes!